# How to place full width menu under logo and sub header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap 3 in combination with a classic aspx page and I want to accomplish something which looks as follows (with Bootstrap or without):

[image]

To do this I have the following code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-brand">

            <asp:Label ID="MainHeader" runat="server" SkinID="MainHeader" Text="OUR BRAND"></asp:Label>

         </div>
     <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
         <asp:Label ID="MainSubHeader" runat="server" SkinID="MainSubHeader" Text="[Sub Title]"></asp:Label>
     </div>
     <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <asp:HyperLink ID="SiteLogoHyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Pages/Welcome.aspx" ImageUrl="[OUR LOGO]">
         </asp:HyperLink>
     </div>

     <div style="border-top-width: 3px; border-top-style: solid;">
     </div><!-- A horizontal row that I prefer to be under the brand, sub header and logo -->

     <div id="divMenu">
           <!-- START SITEMAP MENU-->
         <asp:Menu ID="MainMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="siteMapDS" 
             <StaticItemTemplate>
                        <%# Server.HtmlEncode((string)Eval("Text")) %>
             </StaticItemTemplate>
         </asp:Menu>

         <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="siteMapDS" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="False" />
     </div>
         <!-- END SITEMAP MENU-->
     </div>
     <!--navbar-->

     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
               <!-- DISPLAY INFORMATION IF NECESSARY -->
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12" >
             <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
              </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> <!--MAIN CONTENT-->
         </div>
    </div>
</div><!--container-fluid-->
```

The effect is that the brand comes on the left and that the menu is on the right as follows:

[image]

How can I style this in a way that the navigation-bar is underneath the brand and sub-header? It is not necessary to use Bootstrap.

Comment: what if you put `Navigation bar` in new `Row` using class `.row`. and to put the logo on right you may use class `.pull-right`.

Comment: @KheemaPandey I placed the navigation bar (and horizontal bar) in a new row under the `navbar`-div. Then the navigation bar goes to the side one block (e.g., is next to the brand) and the row comes *underneath* the brand, sub-header and logo. :-)

Comment: Oh wait, and when I place it in a `col-lg-12` as well the row comes indeed underneath the logo.But it is still *next* to the sub-header and brand. Same situation as in the picture. :)

Comment: @KheemaPandey Any idea why on IE10 the menu disappears? It works in IE8.

Comment: lets add this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />`

Comment: Wow @KheemaPandey it works actually. :) The menu reappears. It is not full height though and the horizontal row is also gone. Any idea how this is possible and how to make it reappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't exactly define the problem without the complete code, but judging by the image that you posted I think it's a floating issue.

Try clearing the float just before your nav using this:

```
<br style="clear:both;" />
<div id="divMenu">
       <!-- START SITEMAP MENU-->
     <asp:Menu ID="MainMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="siteMapDS" 
         <StaticItemTemplate>
                    <%# Server.HtmlEncode((string)Eval("Text")) %>
         </StaticItemTemplate>
     </asp:Menu>

     <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="siteMapDS" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="False" />
 </div>
```

Hope this helps.